# store the value from an array into variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtzeT.png]

I get these type of array in my jQuery variable. Now I want store each array values in differnt varaible.
(Ex : I want to store `Address` field in one variable).
How to do it? Any suggestion? Here I upload the image, I get that type of array in console.

```
 $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url  : '<?php echo MY_SITE_URL ;?>'+'webapi.php',
                data: { task:'Properties.getSearch',SEARCHID1: SEARCHID1},
                success: function(response)
                {
                     var j= JSON.parse(response);
                     console.log(j);
                }, 

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create variable with get each data into your **json**.

```
var Address = j.Address;
var Status = j.status;
etc...
```